# Keycloak: how to get client_id where the user registered?

Tags: keycloak

I have a realm with several OpenId clients using SSO. I need to determine from which client each Keycloak user came from.

How can I get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I didn't find natively this information in Keycloak's token. So I added a script.

In Authentication > Registration flow, I add an execution of type "Script" with the following function:

```
function authenticate(context) {

    var username = user ? user.username : "anonymous";
    var uri = context.getUriInfo();

    LOG.info("setClientIdAttribute for URI " + context.getUriInfo().getRequestUri());

    if (uri !== null) {
        var clientId = uri.getQueryParameters().getFirst("client_id");

        if (clientId !== null) {
            LOG.info("Attribute 'origin' set with value " + clientId + " for user " + username);
            user.setSingleAttribute('origin', clientId);
        }
    }

    context.success();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If decoded each JWT has parameter azp, which is the client id.

Comment: I guess this is the current client id. But what I want is to know the client id where the user created his account.

Answer (score 0):

If you decode the token, the field "aud" is your "client_id".

Check this information using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: I guess this is the current client id. But what I want is to know the client id where the user created his account.